# My Chrome Developer Tools is missing the Animation Inspector button

Tags: web-development, google-chrome

I want to inspect some animations on a site and learnt you can use Chrome's Animation Inpector as detailed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26486866/debug-css-animation-with-chrome-devtools) and [here](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/inspect-styles/animations).

However, my version of Chrome (55.0.2883.75 m (64-bit) on Windows) seems to be missing this button.

Would anyone know how to get it working?

Comment: I'm closing this question as off-topic because it appears to be about a tool for developers as opposed to for webmasters.   Questions about programming and development are better asked at StackOverflow.   However, I'm not sure if questons about tools for developers are on-topic there.  In any case, I added a comment to [Debug CSS animation with Chrome Devtools](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26486866/debug-css-animation-with-chrome-devtools) on SO that tells how to make it work now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ah, found another way to get it working:

Click the 3 dots to the top right, then More Tools, then select Animations

Comment: Thank you @MeltingDog - I've been searching all over for where this disappeared to!